# How to tag the product image in magento?

Tags: image, magento

Ive got a new requirement which has a grouped product and the image of the grouped product has marking in it like 1,2,3 etc in the place of each simple products . While clicking on those markings, it should show a popup window which has the image of that simple product, its name as well as add to cart button. Is there any extension of feature to do that? If not, then how can i do that?? The version of magento Im using is 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 2):

Well I am not sure that such an extension are available. 
My solution is use any of the jQuery or Prototype light-box or popup code and pass product id as parameter. 
Use query string to add product into cart.
http://www.your_domain.com/checkout/cart/add?product=68&qty=1